# Выделение текста по ховеру

Tags: html, css

Как в ховере снять жирное выделение текста в элементе при наведении на него курсором, если этот элемент размечен тегом `b`?

Comment: font-weight: normal;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Супер просто

```css
b:hover {
  font-weight: normal
}
```

```html
<b>Text</b>
```